# How to call a function inside view.py

Tags: python, django, url-routing

This is the current project stucture

```
R6Scorextractor


        R6Scoreex
                 migrations
                 templates
                          R6Scoreex
                                   header.html
                                   home.html


                 __Init__.py
                 settings.py
                 urls.py 
                 views.py
                 models.py
                 apps.py
                 admin.py
                 tests.py
        R6Scorextractor
                 __Init__.py
                 settings.py
                 urls.py 
        manage.py
```

*R6Scorextractor/R6scoreex/urls.py*

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
from django.conf.urls import include

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),




]
```

*R6Scorextractor/R6scoreex/views.py*

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.shortcuts import render

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage
# Create your views here.
from django.http import HttpResponse
import pdb;

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'R6scoreex/home.html')


def simple_upload(request):


    print "Entered simple_upload"

    if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES['myfile']:
        myfile = request.FILES['myfile']
        fs = FileSystemStorage()
        filename = fs.save(myfile.name, myfile)
        uploaded_file_url = fs.url(filename)
        return render(request, 'R6scoreex/home.html', {
            'uploaded_file_url': uploaded_file_url
        })
    return render(request, 'R6scoreex/home.html')
```

*R6Scorextractor/R6Scorextractor/url.py*

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import include

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'', include('R6scoreex.urls')),
]
```

I just want to know how to call simple_upload inside views.py of  R6scoreex module.How to write URL for it , server gives me 404 error when I went with the following

```
url(r'^/simple_upload/$', views.simple_upload, name='simple_upload'),
```

[image]

So what is the reason I am getting 404 error even after adding the above code what am I doing wrong here

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi! Did you write this url(r'^/simple_upload$/', views.simple_upload, name='simple_upload'), in which urls.py? Correct one is R6Scorextractor/R6scoreex/urls.py  Try to remove the $ and / of the regex part to check if it works. Also you dont need to import include there.

Comment: Yes I wrote it in R6scoreex/urls.py I wrote this url(r'^simple_upload/$', views.simple_upload, name='simple_upload'), and it gives me 404. no change this is bugging me for more than 24 hours.

Answer (score 1):

You have a Regex problem most probably.

This pattern works for me: (R6Scorextractor/R6Scorextractor/url.py)

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import include

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^/', include('R6scoreex.urls')),
]
```

And (R6Scorextractor/R6scoreex/urls.py)

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^simple_upload/', views.simple_upload, name='simple_upload'),

]
```

Comment: honestly thats not working for me and I have no idea why is that happening and this is the reason I posted the question itself

Comment: can you do one thing if I can make a zip file of this and sent you the thing can you run it on your system and tell me